# Changing the font in an <ul>

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I am having trouble understanding how to control different elements with my stylesheet classes and id's. I am trying to use an `<ul>` for the footer links, for my website and I want to change the font of the links. Where and how do I apply this? No matter where I apply 'font-family: whatever', nothing changes.

here is my CSS for the ul

```
#footer {
height: 50px;
width: 600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}

#footer ul {
list-style-type: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;

}

#footer  li {
display: inline;

}

#footer  a:link {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

here is the html

```
<div id="footer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> About </a></li> |
<li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li> |
<li><a href="#"> Terms </a></li> |
<li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Also, how do I change the font for my divider between links |  ?

Comment: you might want to note that the only child elements of your <ul> element should be <li> elements - you should not have the | outside of the <li> elements. you should probably not use a list here at all, but that of course it up to you :)

Comment: simple keep it separate li and add new class for the divider.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using `font: Helvetica;`. If you change that to `font-family: Helvetica;` it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/6g8Km/

**Edit:** Well, you *did* have `font: Helvetica`, before your edit.

To style the pipes differently from the links, set `font-family` on `#footer li` to the font you want for the pipes.  Then set `font-family` on `#footer li a:link` to the font you want for the links.

```
#footer  li { 
    font-family: serif;
} 
#footer li a:link { 
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer li a {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Also, enclose your pipe characters in `<span class="pipe">|</span`, then apply a `font-family` to `span.pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

You would put it in the li selector, in your list-item. Additionally, similar to divs, you have spans for small text segments you want to apply specific styling to.

```
<span>|</span>
span { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
```

For instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer ul
{ 
    padding:30px;
}
#footer ul li
{
    font-size:12px;
    list-style:disc;
}
#footer ul li a or #footer li a
{
    color:#333;
}
/*for links inside li*/
```

Just, but the element html name or class with in parent class or id in page.
Enjoy with styles! Also keep rocking with css3!